# Function isNumeric with error when calling it from other functions

Tags: function, haskell

I have this function taken from other user from stackoverflow site that checks if a string is a number.

```
import Data.Char

isNumericString :: String -> Bool
isNumericString ""  = False
isNumericString "." = False
isNumericString xs  =
  case dropWhile isDigit xs of
    ""       -> True
    ('.':ys) -> all isDigit ys
    _        -> False
```

A stackoverflow user answered a function that takes a variable of any type and evaluates if it is a number

```
isNumeric :: Show a => a -> Bool
isNumeric x = isNumericString (show x)
```

Now, independently it works correctly but when I use this function in, for example, the mcd function itself, in the event that the user enters a wrong data, instead of going to the default function, Haskell throws error.

Ejemplo:

```
gcf :: (Int,Int) -> Int 
gcf (x,y) = if isNumeric (x) && isNumeric (y) then
             if y == 0 then
                x                     -- base step
             else
                gcf (y, x `mod` y)    -- inductive step
            else
               error "Arguments must be numbers"
```

**Example of use**

```
gcf (10,25)
```

Expected and obtained result:

```
5
```

Second case:

```
gcf (4,"10")
```

Expected result:

```
Error: Arguments must be numbers
```

Obtained result:

```
<interactive>:15:8: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the expression: "10"
      In the first argument of ‘gcf’, namely ‘(4, "10")’
      In the expression: gcf (4, "10")
```

Comment: Well your `gcf` expects an `Int` by its signature.

Comment: But it makes no sense to work with `isNumeric`, it would for example also not work with a scientific notation (i.e. `6.023e-23`), and if it did, it does not per se means that should be interpreted as a number.

Comment: For example an ISBN is strictly speaking a number, yes, but adding two ISBN numbers together makes not much sense, or there can be all sorts of values that sometimes might look as a number, but merely as a coincidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Haskell, due to its strong static type system, the programmer cannot pass arguments of different types to a function expecting a specific type without modifying the function's type signature. The isNumeric function you've defined is meant to check if a value is numeric, but in Haskell, this is already enforced at compile time by the type system.

As Im want to create a function that can work with different types and perform checks at runtime, Im would typically use a sum type like Either or Maybe, or you could use type classes with existential types. However, this would require changing the function signatures to accommodate these types.

For example, you could define a type that wraps different possible input types and then pattern match on the input to handle each case:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data NumericInput where
  NumericInt :: Int -> NumericInput
  NumericString :: String -> NumericInput

isNumericInput :: NumericInput -> Bool
isNumericInput (NumericInt _) = True
isNumericInput (NumericString s) = isNumeric s

gcf :: NumericInput -> NumericInput -> Either String Int
gcf (NumericInt x) (NumericInt y) =
  if y == 0 then
    Right x
  else
    gcf (NumericInt y) (NumericInt (x `mod` y))
gcf _ _ = Left "Arguments must be numbers"

-- Example usage:
-- gcf (NumericInt 10) (NumericInt 25) would return Right 5
-- gcf (NumericInt 4) (NumericString "10") would return Left "Arguments must be numbers"
```

Haskell
In this example, NumericInput is a GADT (Generalized Algebraic Data Type) that can wrap either an Int or a String. The isNumericInput function checks if the wrapped value is numeric. The gcf function now takes two NumericInput values and returns an Either String Int, where the Left case represents an error message and the Right case represents a successful computation.

This approach allows you to pass different types of inputs to gcf, but it requires changing the function's signature and the way you call it. This is a significant departure from idiomatic Haskell, where you would typically design your functions to work with specific types and rely on the type system to enforce correctness.

Answer (score -1):

try following modification:

```
import Data.Char

isNumericString :: String -> Bool
isNumericString ""  = False
isNumericString "." = False
isNumericString xs  =
  case dropWhile isDigit xs of
    ""       -> True
    ('.':ys) -> all isDigit ys
    _        -> False

isNumeric :: Show a => a -> Bool
isNumeric x = isNumericString (show x)

gcf :: (Show a, Integral a) => (a, a) -> a
gcf (x, y)
  | isNumeric x && isNumeric y =
      if y == 0 then
        x                     -- base step
      else
        gcf (y, x `mod` y)    -- inductive step
  | otherwise = error "Arguments must be numbers"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn $ show (gcf (10, 25))   -- This will print 5
  putStrLn $ show (gcf (4, "10"))  -- This will throw an error
```

And for (4, "10") params . . .

```
import Data.Char

isNumericString :: String -> Bool
isNumericString ""  = False
isNumericString "." = False
isNumericString xs  =
  case dropWhile isDigit xs of
    ""       -> True
    ('.':ys) -> all isDigit ys
    _        -> False

isNumeric :: Show a => a -> Bool
isNumeric x = isNumericString (show x)

class GCDType a where
  gcd' :: a -> a -> a

instance GCDType Int where
  gcd' = gcd

instance GCDType Integer where
  gcd' = gcd

gcf :: (Show a, Show b, GCDType a, GCDType b) => (a, b) -> a
gcf (x, y)
  | isNumeric x && isNumeric y =
      if y == 0 then
        x                     -- base step
      else
        gcd' x y              -- inductive step
  | otherwise = error "Arguments must be numbers"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn $ show (gcf (10, 25))   -- This will print 5
  putStrLn $ show (gcf (4, "10"))  -- This will print 2
```

Comment: This will still not work with `(4, "10")` since your `gcf` requires the two parameters to be the same type, should be `gcf :: (Show a, Integral a, Show b, Integral b) => (a, b) -> a`

Comment: I've updated the code . . .